# Sum of large numbers in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, biginteger

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class LargeSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
        int limit=inp.nextInt();
        BigInteger[] arr=new BigInteger[limit];
        for (int i=0; i<limit; i++) 
            arr[i]=new BigInteger(inp.nextLine());  //runtime error
        BigInteger sum=new BigInteger(String.valueOf(arr[0]));
        for (int i=1; i<limit;i++) 
            sum=sum.add(arr[i]);
    }

}
```

I've written a code to find the sum of user given amount of large numbers in java using BigInteger class, but I reached a runtime error "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Zero length BigInteger". How can I fix this issue?
Sample input:
5
37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250
23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676

Comment: Questions must provide a [mcve]. What's the input causing that error?

Comment: First int input represents the amount of numbers user want to enter, and each input String numbers are 50 digit ones.
Sample input:
5
37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250
23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676

Comment: Still no a [mcve]. Which line in the input is causing the error? A [mcve] should provide a `main()` function and a description of HOW the input is provided to the scanner

Comment: Edit your question to add the information. Comment are hard to read and could be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Advance to the next line first.

```java
int limit=inp.nextInt();
inp.nextLine();
```

Or, use the *[Integer#parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))* method.

```java
int limit=Integer.parseInt(inp.nextLine());
```

Output

```
5
37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250
23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676

272819012982030361314614767301043585006837989465343
```